# Disabling PrimeFaces selectOneMenu component in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How to disable selectOneMenu

If I add this in < p:calendar> tag 
`onclick="document.getElementById('formId:textInputId').disabled=true"`

it will disable < p:inputText with given ID, but if I try to do the same for  < p:selectOneMenu> it will not work?

*I have locked for id names on html page in same way as I did for inputText. it looks something like this j_idt13:projectName*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wand to disable the component from javascript, use Client Side API's `disable()` and `enable()` functions.

```
<p:selectOnceMenu widgetVar="selectOneMenuWidget" />
```

And From Javascript you can call:

```
PF('selectOneMenuWidget').disable();
```

Comment: Thanks for life! There is no way to disable it  by id?

Comment: Note that this is just a client-side disable, and so an attacker could still submit data by editing the request. Using JSF's `disabled` attribute disables the component on the server-side. Probably not an issue, but good to know.